# Given the relation: $a\to b \iff \frac{lcm(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}$ is a prime , prove or reject the following:

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Given the relation: $a\to b \iff \frac{lcm(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}$ is a prime , prove or reject the following:
>   1-For any arbitrary positive integers $a,k$, the chain $a\to b\to c\to \cdots \to k$ is possible
>   2-Given arbitrary positive integers $a,b_1,b_2,\cdots b_m$  , there is a chain starting with $a$ in which all $b_i$'s appear just once
>   3-Starting with any arbitrary positive integer $a$, there is an infinite chain containing JUST all multiples of $a$
>   4-Starting with any arbitrary positive integer $a$,there is an infinite chain containing ALL squares
>   5-Given arbitrary positive integers $a,b$ ,there is a chain  starting with $a$ in which all numbers are less than $b$ and all numbers less than $b$ have appeared  just once

Please help on this problem.

Comment: Can you show that the relation holds if and only if $a/b$ is either a prime or the reciprocal of a prime? If you can do that, the rest should be easy.

Comment: I think one of the relations $a=bp$ or $b=ap$ must hold for some prime $p$

Comment: Are you attempting to define a $\to$ relation here, or is this some predefined notation?

Comment: The notation is unpleasant because $\to$ is a symmetric relation but has been written with a clearly asymmetric symbol :(

Comment: @DanielV It's not a predefined  notation

Comment: @PatrickStevens So you suggest a better symbol or notation!!

Comment: Anything, really. The obvious choice is $\sim$, but there's $\leftrightarrow$ too.

Comment: I believe here  the problem itself is more important,which seems a fairly difficult one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the hint by drhab it is not difficult to show that either $a=bp$ or $b=ap$ for some prime $p$. In other words, we can move along the chain by either multiplying or dividing by any prime $p$.

1. For this question, look at the prime factorization of $a$ and $k$ and then for each prime $p$, keep multiplying/dividing by $p$ until you get the number of $p$'s you need in $k$.
2. The trouble here is that we run into the risk of running into the $b_i$'s multiple times if we construct a chain willy-nilly. To avoid this, find a prime that is not contained in $a$ or any of the $b_i$'s, say $q$. Then you can form the chain,

$$a \to qa \to \dots \to qb_1 \to b_1 \to qb_1$$
$$ \dots \to qb_2 \to b_2 \to qb_2$$
$$\dots$$
$$\dots \to qb_n \to b_n,$$

making sure to keep the $q$ around for the terms not explicitly listed above. Since we are always carrying around a prime factor that none of the $b_i$'s have, we don't have to worry about repeating them.

3. Notice that we can go from $a$ to $ka$ by simply multiplying by primes in the prime factorization of $k$ until we reach $ka$ and by doing so, each element in the chain is also a multiple of $a$. We can also use that same chain but backwards to go from $ka$ to $a$ that also uses those multiples of $a$. Then, to get **all** the multiples of $a$, you can start at $a$ and create a chain to $2a$ as described above, chain back to $a$, chain to $3a$, chain back to $a$, etc
4. I don't see what the issue here is since there isn't any real restrictions and we can always chain between two positive integers...just start at $a$, chain to $1$, then chain to $4$, chain to $9$, etc
5. Not sure if this is always possible since the chain must start at $a$ and if $a \geq b$, then it's impossible to construct such a chain.

EDIT:
For problem 5, it seems impossible even if the first part of the chain $a$ is allowed to be bigger than $b$. Suppose $a$ is composed of two large primes $p$ and $q$ so that $a = pq$ and $p > b$ and $q > b$. The only possibilities for the second element of the chain (assuming the second element is smaller than $a$) is either $p$ or $q$ both of which is larger than $b$ thus making it impossible to construct the chain asked of in problem 5.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $a=p_1^{a_1}\times\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ and $b=p_1^{b_1}\times\cdots p_k^{b_k}$ where the $p_i$ are primes and the $a_i,b_i$ are nonnegative integers then

- $\gcd(a,b)=p_1^{\min(a_1,b_1)}\times\cdots\times p_k^{\min(a_k,b_k)}$
- $\text{lcm}(a,b)=p_1^{\max(a_1,b_1)}\times\cdots\times p_k^{\max(a_k,b_k)}$

Comment: My first trouble is how to show $a=bp$ or $b=ap$ for some prime $p$

Comment: If you calculate the quotient on base of my answer then you find that it equals $p_1^{c_1}\times\cdots\times p_1^{c_k}$ with $c_i=\max(a_i,b_i)-\min(a_i,b_i)$. Now realize that $p_1^{c_1}\times\cdots\times p_1^{c_k}$ is a prime if and only if exactly one of $c_i$ takes value $1$ and the others take value $0$. If $c_i=0$ then $a_i=b_i$ ($k-1$ cases) and if $c_i=1$ (one case) then $a_i=b_i+1$ or $b_i=a_i+1$.